# Iminuit fitting algorithm?

Tags: python, iminuit

Does anyone knows what algorithm is used for the python iminuit fitting package, when no attribute is specified?

Comment: Can't you read the docs for that package or even look at its source code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documentation](https://iminuit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#technical-stuff) says it uses the Quasi Newton Method and DFP formula.

You can see in the [source code](https://github.com/iminuit/iminuit/blob/fc5cc5d89f15921fbd78b27396eda22a5f99b487/Minuit/src/MnStrategy.cxx#L43) what the default strategy looks like:

```
void MnStrategy::SetMediumStrategy() {
   // set minimum strategy (1) the default
   fStrategy = 1;
   SetGradientNCycles(3);
   SetGradientStepTolerance(0.3);
   SetGradientTolerance(0.05);
   SetHessianNCycles(5);
   SetHessianStepTolerance(0.3);
   SetHessianG2Tolerance(0.05);
   SetHessianGradientNCycles(2);
}
```